# three.js - text next to line

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've a tube geometry in a scene which is built from data loaded as JSON. I've to put a line as a marker at each segment. And for that I am taking centroid of a face as starting point and added 10 to each co-ordinate of centroid as end point of line.

Please find the jsfiddle of [tube with line](http://jsfiddle.net/RnFqz/13/)

Please find below the code of adding line from the center of a face.

```
var lineGeo, lineMat, line;
var fx=tube.faces[3].centroid.x;
var fy=tube.faces[3].centroid.y;
var fz=tube.faces[3].centroid.z;
lineGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
lineGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(fx, fy, fz), new THREE.Vector3(fx+50, fy+50, fz+50));

lineMat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, lineWidth: 2});                 
line = new THREE.Line(lineGeo, lineMat);
line.type = THREE.Lines;
tubeMesh.add(line);
```

Now how do I put text at the end of a line ?
In a production environment tube is built with 2000 co-ordinates and there will be 200 lines as marker. I've to put text at the end of each marker (line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you take the coords of your line, apply some offset to it and build a plane just above it. That way you could display a texture with your text on that plane. Later on, just set 'opacity' param to '0' by default and return it to '1' as you pick your face. And there are few ways you could make those textures:

1) You can import all of your text as images (which is not your case, since you'll have more than 200 to go).

2) You can create canvas element, draw some text on it with CSS and later on use this canvas as your texture for a certain plane. Personally think this is the best solution in your case, since generating real time 3D dynamic text will just put your fps to the floor.

So first you create new canvas element:

```
texture_placeholder = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
texture_placeholder.width = 100;
texture_placeholder.height = 20;
```

Then set some text inside of your canvas:

```
var context = texture_placeholder.getContext( '2d' );
context.fillStyle = '#f00'; 
context.textAlign = "center";
context.textBaseline = "middle";           
context.font = ' bold 150px';             
context.fillText('This is the 3rd face!', texture_placeholder.width / 2, texture_placeholder.height / 2);
```

Then create texture based on canvas:

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture( texture_placeholder );
texture.needsUpdate = true;
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, overdraw: true, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
```

Finnaly, set your new plane mesh:

```
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 20 );
var text = new THREE.Mesh( plane, material )
```

Hope that helps! Here is your example: http://jsfiddle.net/WT6jL/1/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example. You are right after adding 3d text fps suddenly drops. I will try and let you know. Using canvas as texture can also solve another issue I am facing.-@Alex Under

Comment: It works fine. Is is possible to create such a map for the whole tube geometry ? @Alex Under

Comment: Well, basically what you do is just setting the source of your texture to the source of your specific canvas element (which could contain whatever you like, an entire website, if you wish). In other words, you create your texture map not from outsource image on your server (or from elsewhere on the web), but from within your own page’s element.

Comment: Think of it’s this way: a ‘canvas’ is something that painters use to draw pictures at. So, at the end – they’ve got their piece of art at their canvases (a picture). On the other hand – you have photos and stuff that are pictures (images) too. So, for the three.js texture it does not matter what kind of “picture” you use – photo, image, a painted picture or anything else. The only difference is that YOU are the painter that can draw anything you want on your canvas and later on set it as your texture map. And yes, you can apply canvas texture map to any mesh in your scene in three.js.

Comment: forgot to mention one detail: (as far as I know) when you are using canvas for your textures - you are not relying upon the GPU, so using this method to much could slow thing up. Take that in consideration. Try using three.js proper image loader whenever your can: `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(img.src);`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on using canvas as three.js texture. I am going to post another question which is related to this and the performance of 3d model using `CanvasRenderer` and `WebGLRenderer`.- @Alex Under

Answer (score 1):

Here is another complete detailed example of creating an image on a canvas element from text, and then applying that image as a texture in three.js:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

Hope it helps!